# I occasionally get a message in Superuser that it works better with Java script enabled.

Tags: support, javascript, firefox

I occasionally get a message in Superuser that it works better with Java script enabled. However, when I go to Javascript, it is already enabled.

Why would this happen?

I'm using Windows XP and Firefox version 3.6.3.

EDIT: The same flag has now come up on Meta.
Edit:  I have discovered that this is triggered by some program I have installed in Firefox. I notice that as I get to the end of a page, if ther is another page, a pop-up box appears at the bottom right corner and says: "Loading next page". Immediately after that, I get the "Javascript message.

Comment: What version of Firefox? Are you running no-script or any other addon that may interrupt regular javascript operation?

Comment: Version 3.6.3.

I am not running another toolbar.

Thanks

Comment: ps: not running no script either.

Comment: adblock? firebug?

Comment: None of those...

Comment: Go to Tools>Add-ons and tell us what's listed in the first pane there.

Comment: *sigh* for people who say "Java script" or even *gasp!* just "java".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should only appear if JavaScript is disabled. View source to see why..

```
<noscript> 
    <div id="noscript-warning">Meta Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled</div> 
</noscript>
```

See [noscript tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.1) documentation

Comment: I'm not highly computer literate. How do I "view source"?

Comment: OK. I found "view" and looked at "page source". What am I looking for?

Comment: @Xavierjazz No need to hunt it down yourself - Jeff posted the relevant source above.

Comment: @xavier what I mean is, there has to be something wrong with your browser configuration to see this -- by W3C standards definition it means JavaScript is somehow *disabled* for you. Have you tried in a different browser?

Comment: Not yet, thanks. Too busy. I'll let you know.

Comment: I have discovered an aspect of the problem. Please see the question again for the edit.
Regards.

Comment: @Jeff I am also having the same sporadic problem within Chrome (6.0.472.63, portable install). I have Javascript enabled for all sites, and this seems to only happen on the older Stack sites' parent sites. Meta sites and all Area51 gen work as expected.

Comment: @mfg we have no other reports of this and use Chrome 6 every day across the entire dev team. I strongly suspect whatever "portable install" is, that might be your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're probably right. I guess I was hoping (?) there were other reports and a fix.